# How can I read and parse a BSON dump file in Spark?

Tags: mongodb, scala, apache-spark, bson

I have a couple of BZ2 Mongo DB BSON Dumps in HDFS that need to be analysed. I'm using Spark 2.0.1 and Scala 2.11.8. Currently I'm using the Spark Shell.

I tried using mongo-spark connector by creating an RDD as follows -

```
val rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(path="hdfs:///pathtofile/dump.bson.bz2",
classOf[com.mongodb.hadoop.BSONFileInputFormat].asSubclass(classOf[org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat[Object, org.bson.BSONObject]]), 
classOf[Object], 
classOf[org.bson.BSONObject])
```

and then simply reading it using `rdd.take(1)`.

Executing that gives me `java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data.`

I also tried the same step by extracting the bz2 archive. It results in the same error.

How can I address the mentioned error? Any alternative method to read BSON dumps in Spark?

Comment: Just a hunch try to add the mongo connector jar in the spark.setJars(), because this usually arises when the worker does not know how to read it ! And hence I am saying this. and it might work !