# How to read and write BSON files with Spark?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

I have many MongoDB dumps in gzip compressed BSON files, each with multiple documents. I would like to read them directly to Spark, ideally partitioning on individual document level.

Previous discussions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40153988/how-can-i-read-and-parse-a-bson-dump-file-in-spark), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39851476/rdd-of-bsonobject-to-a-dataframe)) are old and use the depracated Hadoop Mongo connector. The new, actively maintained [Spark Mongo connector](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-spark/tree/master/src/main/scala/com/mongodb/spark) seems to implement a DefaultSource interface, a couple custom partitioners, and a connection layer.

I would like to extract (or contribute) a way to read a multi-document BSON file from disk into a DataFrame, such that different documents can be loaded into different partitions. Writing would also be great to have for completeness, but I'm not sure how robust can writing to a single file from multiple writers be. I am new to Spark and unsure where to start.

Comment: I believe the MongoDB SPARK connector enables you to read MongoDB collections into the SPARK dataframe environment which is *not* what you're going after.   You want to read BSON files directly -- it's actually independent of MongoDB.  This is a *very* worthwhile pursuit because it bridges high performance OLTP (MongoDB) to lower performance blob storage BUT retaining full type fidelity.